# bitwise operations with Z3 in python

Tags: python, bit-manipulation, z3

once again I'm struggling with Z3. I'm trying to build a code from a binary I disassembled with IDA:
[image: ida graph]

This function is being called 0x80 times. ecx is initialized with 0x40. [rdi+8] initialized with 0xDEADFACEDEADBEEF. rsi gets every byte from vector "vec" which I try to find and it's values can only be 0x30,0x31 and 0x32. I'm not sure if my logic is right or is that I'm not using the right Z3 function. It's not SAT and It should be, because eventually vector 'v1' in my problem should contain the value 0x123456701234567. My code:

```
from z3 import *

def set_number(vec,size): #vec
    for i in range(0, size * 8 - 8, 8):
        val = Extract(i + 7, i, vec)
        val = BV2Int(val,False)
        return Or(val==0x30,val == 0x31, val == 0x32)

s = z3.Solver()

size = 0x80
ecx = 0x40
v1 = BitVecVal(0xDEADFACEDEADBEEF,64)
vec = BitVec("inf",size*8) # <content from d.d file>
s.add(set_number(vec,size)) #40 bytes of {0,1,2}

for i in range(0, size*8-8, 8):
    val = Extract(i + 7, i, vec)
    val = BV2Int(val,False)
    if(val == 0x30):
        v1 = RotateLeft(v1, ecx)
        v1 = v1 >> 1
        v1 *= 2
        v1 = RotateRight(v1, ecx)
        ecx = ecx - 1
        s.add(ecx>=0)
    elif(val == 0x31):
        s.add(ecx<40 and ecx>=0)
        ecx = ecx+1
        v1 = RotateLeft(v1,ecx)
        v1 = v1 >> 1
        v1 *= 2
        v1 = RotateRight(v1,ecx)
        ecx = ecx+1
    elif (val==0x32):
        s.add(ecx < 40 and ecx >= 0)
        ecx = ecx + 1
        v1 = RotateLeft(v1, ecx)
        v1 = v1 >> 1
        v1 *= 2
        v1 = v1 | 1
        v1 = RotateRight(v1, ecx)
        ecx = ecx+1
s.add(v1 == 0x123456701234567)
s.check()
```

As always, many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems here, but the most important one is your use of `if-then-else`. When you are using a symbolic value, you cannot use Python's if-then-else. Instead, you have to use z3's `If` construct.

In your program, your if-then-else's are concretely evaluated and thus you get a bogus assertion at the end. You can validate this by putting a `print s.sexpr()` before you call `check`.

Start by replacing all your `if-then-else's` with calls to `If` function. And at each step look at `s.sexpr()` (let's say after every `add`) and make sure it contains the right expressions. That should lead you to a proper coding of the problem. Start by reading here: https://z3prover.github.io/api/html/namespacez3py.html#a782883a35d4c6a0be62cd5333645dbaf

## z3 coding style

The following is how I'd code your problem in z3py. Note that I merely transliterated your python code, so if you've any bugs in your coding there, they will be preserved. Note how all symbolic "if-then-else" computations are done separately and merged via calls to z3py's `If`.

```py
from z3 import *

size = 0x80
vec = BitVec("inf", size * 8)

s = Solver()

# Every byte in vec is either 0x30, 0x31 or 0x32
for i in range(0, size*8, 8):
    b = Extract(i+7, i, vec)
    s.add(Or(b == 0x30, b == 0x31, b == 0x32))

def setLastBit(v):
    return Concat(Extract(63, 1, v), BitVecVal(1, 1))

def clearLastBit(v):
    return Concat(Extract(63, 1, v), BitVecVal(0, 1));

def if30(inp, ecx):
    inp = RotateLeft(inp, ecx)
    inp = clearLastBit(inp)
    inp = RotateRight(inp, ecx)
    ecx = ecx - 1
    return inp, ecx

def if31(inp, ecx):
    ecx = ecx + 1
    inp = RotateLeft(inp, ecx)
    inp = clearLastBit(inp)
    inp = RotateRight(inp, ecx)
    ecx = ecx + 1
    return inp, ecx

def if32(inp, ecx):
    ecx = ecx + 1
    inp = RotateLeft(inp, ecx)
    inp = setLastBit(inp)
    inp = RotateRight(inp, ecx)
    ecx = ecx + 1
    return inp, ecx

v1  = BitVecVal(0xDEADFACEDEADBEEF, 64)
ecx = BitVecVal(0x40, 64)

for i in range(0, size*8, 8):
    val   = Extract(i + 7, i, vec)
    val30 = if30(v1, ecx)
    val31 = if31(v1, ecx)
    val32 = if32(v1, ecx)
    v1    = If(val == 0x30, val30[0], If(val == 0x31, val31[0], val32[0]))
    ecx   = If(val == 0x30, val30[1], If(val == 0x31, val31[1], val32[1]))

s.add(v1 == 0x123456701234567)

print (s.sexpr())
print (s.check())
```

When I run this, unfortunately, z3 prints the program internally generated (you can inspect it to get an idea of how things work under the hood), but it doesn't come back quickly to say `sat` or `unsat`. There could be multiple reasons for this:

- The algorithm as you coded may not be quite correct. I'd recommend studying the program as I wrote it and make sure it captures what you intended. See if you can follow the generated programs (you can add `print (s.sexpr())` at strategic places to see what code gets generated at each step.
- If the coding is incorrect, then hopefully you'll fix it in this style and have z3 find your `vec` value. If it is correct but z3 doesn't answer your query in a reasonable amount of time, then this just means that the problem is just too difficult for z3 to handle. I'd recommend keeping your `vec` short: Instead of the current 64-byte size, start with something much smaller and see if z3 can handle it. (Say a few bytes to start with.) That can also enable further debugging if your understanding of the algorithm is correct.

Best of luck!

Comment: Hi Alias, thank you very much for answering. I read the documentation and spent two hours trying to do something, but I'm really lost. It's very poorly documented and it frustrates me, maybe z3 is not the tool for solving such problems?

It says If function is for if-then-else condition. But what does it mean? what can I understand from that?
I tried many combination, like:
If(val==0x30, <call some function which does something with v1 and ecx>, <call for function which takes care of val==0x31)

Comment: For example, if val==0x30, I wrote the following: If(val == 0x30, f1(v1,ecx), f2(v1,ecx)) with the logic that if it's value is 0x30, I will just to f1, otherwise to f2. I'm obviously wrong, but I couldn't find a single example on the internet :(

Comment: I also tried the logic in https://www.cs.tau.ac.il/~msagiv/courses/asv/z3py/guide-examples.htm by doing If(val==0x30, True, Or(val==0x31, val==0x32)) but how do I continue from here? how can I know the I received True?

Comment: In an `If` call, you put your entire `then` clause in the second argument, and `else` clause in the third. There's really no notion of "continuing." Remember, you're in the symbolic land, so both of those cases are possible, so in a sense you're continuing in both directions and z3 "merges" those results for you automatically. That is, control flow becomes data-flow in symbolic programming.

Comment: Hi again. I cannot put 6 lines of code in my then clause: If(val==0x31, <HERE>, else)
Should I define a function and put it there?

Comment: Z3 has no notion of "code", it's all just logical expressions, i.e., you need an expression that represents the constraints over the inputs and outputs of the relevant piece of code. Z3 will see only the bits in `s.add(x)` everything else is executed as normal Python.

Comment: I added code showing how you should code this in z3py. Hopefully, it'll get you started in the right direction.

Comment: @alias thank you very much! I definitely wasn't near your solution. Unfortunately, it produces "unknown" when running it. I checked with print(s.sexpr()) and it's blank for some reason. If I use the "set_number" function it adds it's constraints but it seems that it breaks in the last for loop...

Comment: When I run the program exactly as I posted, it does print the solver state  and I see a whole program printed. Can you replicate that? Since this is a pure bitvector problem, Z3 will *never* say "unknown" for it: Z3 has a complete decision procedure for bit-vectors thus will always solve it, given enough time/resources. (Of course, time/resource requirements might be impractical for difficult problems.) I suspect you made some changes; focus on what you changed and how it changed the solver state.

Comment: Thank you very much @alias, you helped me a lot!